# Store PHP array to csv in Column wise

Tags: php

```
$handle = fopen("googleshopping.csv", "r");
    if ($handle)
    {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false)
        {
          $a=str_replace( array('[',']','(',')','"',"'") , ''  , $buffer );
            $array=explode(",",$a);
            echo'<pre>';
             print_r($array);

        }

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: You've forgot to add a question

Comment: The `if` doesn't seem to have a closing brace. Also, what is your issue?

Comment: i want to store array element is column wise in csv  like  array(
    [0] => 3-238/10B
    [1] => Home Perfect
    [2] =>  $259.00)
array(
[0] => 1689/06
    [1] => Home Perfect
    [2] =>  $1
    [3] => 008.70
    [4] =>  Home Perfect)
array([0] => 4-1604BP/15
    [1] => eBay - homegoodsliquidators
)
store in column form like
3-238/10B Home Perfect $259.00                                                                                        and this is only read code, i dont know how  store result columnwise

Comment: if you have sample data like that please use the "edit" button (under the blue PHP tag) to add it into your question and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it to be clear and readable. Also please give a clear example of exactly what you expect the CSV output to look like (rather than just saying something like "columnwise" which is potentially open to interpretation). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment:
You want to do this:

```
$y = 3; // number of nodes in each column or row. Change if needed.
$arr = array(); //the original one
$newArr = array();
$manipulationArr = array(); //this is an array to manipulate and use to get what you want in the $newArr
$x = 0;
foreach($arr as $e) {
 $manipulationArr[] = $e;
 $x = $x + 1;
 if ($x == $y) {
   $newArr[] = $manipulationArr;
   $manipulationArr = array();
   $x = 0;
 }
}
unset($e);
```

This turns:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

into:

```
$newArr = array(
  array(1,2,3),
  array(4,5,6),
  array(7,8,9)
);
```

Though, that is **row wise**.

For the actual **Column wise** you need to do the **row wise** and then do this:

```
$newArr = array(); //row wise one
$columnWise = array();
$manipulation1 = array();
$manipulation2 = array(); // as many manipulation arrays as the value of $y
$manipulation3 = array();
$x = 0;
foreach ($newArr as $e) {
  $manipulation1[] = $e[0];
  $manipulation2[] = $e[1]; // the pattern continues based on the number of $manipulation arrays
  $manipulation3[] = $e[2];
}

$columnWise[] = $manipulation1;
$columnWise[] = $manipulation2;
$columnWise[] = $manipulation3;

//pattern continues based on the number of $manipulation arrays
```

This means:

`array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` turns into:

```
array(
  array(1, 4, 7),
  array(2, 5, 8),
  array(3, 6, 9)
)
```